# MySQL database has duplicate entries despite unique constraint

Tags: java, mysql, duplicates, prepared-statement, unique

So mySQL database keeps accepting duplicate entries despite the unique constraint I've added. I've been trying to look for a similar question but could not find anything related. I don't know if my prepared statement is wrong or if mySQL database is set up wrong. Here is my code:

```
    Connection con = DB.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null, ps1 = null, ps2 = null, ps3 = null, ps4 = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into users(user_id, username, password, email, phone_number,"
                + "name, fb_id, bio) values (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setString(2, hashedPassword);
        ps.setString(3, email_address);
        ps.setString(4, phone_number);
        ps.setString(5, name);
        ps.setString(6, fb_id);
        ps.setString(7, bio);
        ps.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          try {
              ps.close();
              con.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); }
```

my table has the following columns:

- user_id int(11) PRIMARY,
- username varchar(20) UNIQUE,
- password varchar(100),
- email varchar(30) UNIQUE,
- phone_number varchar(10) UNIQUE,
- fb_id varchar(20) UNIQUE,
- bio FULL TEXT

I've created the table using phpmyadmin and username and fb_id correctly gives me the MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException, but email and phone_number does not give me any errors when inserting duplicate entries. Is there any reason why this would happen? I am pretty lost as to why the unique constraint is not being enforced...

PS. First time posting!

EDIT: Here is the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE users:

`CREATE TABLE users (
 user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 username varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 password varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 email varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 phone_number varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 name varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 fb_id varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 bio text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
 UNIQUE KEY username (username,email,phone_number),
 UNIQUE KEY fb_id (fb_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

Comment: Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;`? It will show the current defined structure of the table, not just what phpMyAdmin chooses.

Comment: it seems as if the unique constraint for username addresses for email and phone number as well? In other words, phone numbers and emails can be the same as long as the username is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have your UNIQUE KEY setup as a composite key.

```
UNIQUE KEY username (username,email,phone_number)
```

This means that the **combination** of username, email and phone number must be unique. It is not specifying each individual column can't contain duplicate values.

For that you should add a `UNIQUE INDEX` to those columns individually where required. For example to make the email field a `UNIQUE INDEX`:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE INDEX(email);
```